# Craft entries related on a category page

Tags: entries, categories

So i'm trying to output blog entries related to a category.

1. I first created a category group ('categories')
2. I added several categories to the group ('innovation', 'teams', etc)
3. I added a category field to my blog post matrix field (post.category)
4. On my blog index page (example.com/blog) I have excerpts of posts and a sidebar which has the categories and their urls

   ```
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('categories') %}

    {% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
   ```
5. When I click on the link it goes to the page I expect (example.com/categories/teams) and is using the template i specified for the template group (categories.html)
6. In the template for the category I can list the title and name but I want to get the entries so I:

   ```
   <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1> <--- just this works
   {% set posts = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
   {% for post in posts %}
   <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

But this didn't work

following http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category

7. then I tried this, thinking specifying the field was necessary

   ```
   <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1> <--- again, this works
   {% set posts = craft.entries({
   section: 'blog',
   relatedTo: {
   targetElement: category,
   field: 'posts.categories'
   }
   }) %}

   {% for post in posts %}
   <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

and this doesn't work either.

Anyways, i'm not sure where I am going wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the relations work on your blog's index page? Try adding `{{ craft.entries.relatedTo(category).first().title }}` to the categories loop.

Comment: Could you enable devMode and tell us what happens if you `{{ dump(posts) }}`?

Comment: So I realized it was the way I was referencing the categories field nested in the matrix in my templates. I tried several different combinations but no luck. Anyways, I then created a categories field (called categories) and added it to my blog entry type. Then in my individual category template (example.com/categories/innovation) I was able to reference the entries this way                                                                                                           ` {% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo(category) %} `

Comment: Great :) Can you create an answer this and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I should note that the `relatedTo` method accepts a `CategoryModel`, *not* the title of a category. What you ended up doing works, but here's the way to do with the `relatedTo` method, which is what I'd suggest for anyone finding this in the future:

`{% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo(craft.categories.slug('your-cat-slug')) %}`

You now have all entries that are associated with the given category, and can loop through them with the usual `{% for entry in entries %}` technique.

**TL;DR**: You can't pass the category name. You *have* to give `relatedTo` an actual `CategoryModel`.